# ROM initialization in VHDL for waveform generator

Tags: vhdl, matlab, rom

I have to create a waveform generator and i used matlab to generate the sine wave. Now my TA told me to store the points from the wave in a ".mem" file then initialize the ROM by i guess importing them.

I don't really know how to initialize it and can't seem to find any references to
.mem files being used in vhdl.

I have the wave but i need help with creating the ROM and initializing it by using the values from matlab.

Comment: Just turn the sinewave into a constant array of numbers in VHDL. Clean and portable. A constant array should synthesise to a ROM.

Comment: Knowing the FPGA tool you're using may help. In e.g. Quartus or Vivado, you can instantiate a block RAM in their IP tool, configure it to be read-only, and point to a memory initialization file.

Comment: I am using Quartus

Comment: Please have a look at this Look Up Tabel (LUT). A.k.a. ROM or others call it Direct Digital Synthesis (DDS). At the end, it's a function calulation the content of a ROM or LUT. https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/lut/lut_Sine.vhdl?ts=2